# C# namespaces in web.config

Tags: c#, web-config

Coming from a VB background and being forced to learn C# I have hit the first hurdle.

In VB i could put all the namespaces I wanted available across the entire app in the web.config file and it would be available in each code behind file without me having to add import statements.

```
<namespaces>
<clear/>
<add namespace="System"/>
<add namespace="System.Collections"/>
<add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
```

It seems Visual Studio can't do this with C# and I have to add using statements all over the place.

Please tell me I'm missing something obvious and there is a way to get this done.

Comment: Forced huh? You'll look back at this moment in the future with fond regard.

Comment: I hope so. Right now I'm about to throw something through a window :)

Comment: I grudgingly concede that you may have been right Jon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For C#, the namespaces entered in the web.config will be recognized in .aspx files, but not codebehind. I don't think it will take you long to adjust (Ctrl-. will let you quickly add a namespace when you type a class name that doesn't have the namespace referenced).

Answer (score 3):

This ability is only for VB.NET, the C# project does not support it :/.
But, you can create a template for new source code file ( [C# Wizard Templates in Visual Studio .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/VisualStudioTemplates.aspx) , [How To: Edit Visual Studio Templates](http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/Content/HowToEditVSTemplates.aspx) ) and change default namespaces as you wish.