# How to add namespaces in web.config file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, namespaces, web-config

I am using VS 2008 and C# but when I  added namespace in `web.config` file, that namespace is not imported or included in `code behind or aspx`

I have also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438199/c-namespaces-in-web-config) question but not get the required answer.

web.config code

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Data" />
        <add namespace="System.Text"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>  
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The purpose of the namespace section is to get around having to do the import in the .aspx page.  Code behind in C# still requires you to have the using statements at the top of your .cs file.

There is no way to get around this.

Comment: Surely you meant `using statements` and not `the imports directive` for a cs file :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Well... yes that would be the *correct* term.. ;)

Answer (score 35):

You need to put them in the correct `<system.web>` section. e.g.:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Data" />
        <add namespace="System.Text"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>  
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

***and* put them in the correct web.config**

i.e. the second `web.config` file is the `Views` folder and is specific to views. These settings do not go in the *root* web.config.

The purpose of these settings is to make the libraries available to the ASPX pages (e.g. for Intellisense) and it is not used for the code-behind. You still need to have `using` statements in your actual code as that is just plain c# programming.

Comment: Are you actually expecting them to appear in the text of your ASPX files? If so that is not their purpose. With the config settings you no longer need to have includes for those DLLs in your ASPX files (just in the code behind).

Comment: @Chris Lively: Then what is the purpose adding namespace it in web.config file?

Comment: @jams - If you need to add the namespaces to _every_ page, this will import them automatically. No need for extra imports.

Comment: @Oded:That is the problem it is not importing on `code behind`.

Comment: @jams - You might be re-importing existing adds. Did you try adding a `<clear />` element before the adds?

Comment: @Oded:I did exactly but no success. Have you tried it on your system?

Comment: @Oded: it doesn't work in c# code behind files.  You have to include the imports line.

Comment: @ChrisLively - It's not supposed to. It is a substitution for `@ import` directives (which only apply to the `.aspx` page, not the code behind). See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164642.aspx).

Comment: @Oded - Yeah, I understand that.  The OP doesn't.  He wants it to work for code behind.