# Namespaces in web.config file not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, namespaces, web-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add namespaces in web.config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586499/how-to-add-namespaces-in-web-config-file)

I am trying to add namespace in web.config file, so that I can use it in all web pages (in `code behind`). But it is not working. 
Has anybody tried it ? I have asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586499/how-to-add-namespaces-in-web-config-file) before but not get any suitable answer.

To better understand here is `code behind` file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestWeb
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.BackColor = Color.Red;// It is not working.
        }
    }
}
```

This is `web.config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <clear/>
        <add namespace="System.Drawing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Edit

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestWeb._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:label ID="Label1" runat="server" text="Label"></asp:label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: reposting the exact same question within 3 hours of asking your first one isn't wise.  If you have additional details, then you should update your first question.

Comment: What paths are the ASPX and Web.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this and then try.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <clear/>
        <add namespace="System.Drawing" />
        <add namespace="System" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `<namespaces>` element only applies to aspx pages.

Unlike VB.Net, C# has no mechanism to automatically include namespaces in ordinary code files.

Comment: It is not working in `aspx` also.

Comment: Please show your `aspx`.

Comment: Please see my edit question with `aspx` code.

Answer (score 2):

The namespaces configuration section is for pages, not code behind. A code behind file express **all** namespace imports within itself. The namespaces included in configuration will be included in the dynamic class that is generated from your *.aspx* page.

Answer (score 0):

As SLaks says, that will not work.  If you're looking for a shortcut to always having a namespace included, consider editing the default VS templates, so that it's always there when you create a new one.