# Call c# function of global class from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a global function that returns some string.
I need to access to that function from JavaScript in one of the pages and set returned value to JavaScript variable.

Example:-

```
var jsvariable = <%GlobalClass.MethodReturningString();%>;
```

How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by *global* class? Is that method static? What happens when you try the code sample in your question?

Comment: Yes, the global class and method are static. When i use my sample i get site error: “The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks  (ie. <% ... %>).

Comment: For the error you've stated, could you try the scriptlets with <%= %> or <%$ %>

Comment: Or `<%# ... %>` followed by `DataBind()`.

Comment: Read [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/abdullaabdelhaq/archive/2009/09/16/how-to-fix-this-the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blocks-i-e-lt-gt.aspx) related to your error.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call C# function like this. you need to create a web service or webmethod
in order to call this function.
Please see this link it will help you.
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps :

1. Right click on your website or web application and add a WebHandler. The extension for the webhandler is '.ashx'. Let's say you name your handler as 'Handler.ashx'
2. Open the Handler.ashx file and within the ProcessRequest method write the following :

   `context.Response.Headers.Clear();
   context.Response.Write(GlobalClass.MethodReturningString(););
   context.Response.Flush();`
3. In your javascript, perform an ajax call using jQuery :

   `$.ajax({
   url:'someUrl/Handler.ashx',
   type:'GET',
   success : function(data){
   var someJavascriptVariable = data;
   }
   });`

NOTE: This is a quick and dirty write so I'm not guaranteeing  that the code will surely work, but it's a point for you to start with.

Answer (score 0):

May i thick You cannot do this but u can access ur c# function using ajax

For Example

```
   $.post('url', {parameter : parameter }, function (result) {

         // here the result is your function return value or output

   },"json");
```

URL FORMAT : '/pageurl/methodname'

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as a clarification, it seems that you're not trying to actually call a C# method from Javascript, but rather render the return from a C# method inside the page so that it can be used as a Javascript variable value on the client side.

In order to do that you need to update you syntax like:

```
var jsvariable = '<%= GlobalClass.MethodReturningString() %>';
```

Please note that if your class is not in the same namespace as the inherited page from the code behind file, then you need to import its namespace like below:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="GlobalClassNamaspace" %>
```

The namespace import can also be done globally (and it will be automatically available in all of the site's pages), using the web.config file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586499/how-to-add-namespaces-in-web-config-file).

If you were to actually need to call a C# method from Javascript, which would have been needed if you wanted to dynamically use its results from client side code, then that could be accomplished through [Ajax](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx).