# Build Library To Automatically Referenced Locations with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, libraries

I would like to remove a step of the process when building libraries in C# with Visual Studio, like how the `System` libraries can simply be referenced by adding the statement: `using System` to the top of the file.

Normally when building a class library, you have to add a reference to the library in the project you want to consume the library from, and then you can add the using statement on the top of the file you wish to reference the library from.

Is there some way to remove the step of needing to explicitly add a reference (the step accomplishable via a right click on the project in the solution explorer in Visual Studio)? Perhaps by building class libraries to a specific location that Visual Studio automatically adds as referenced when creating new projects to consume the library?

The end goal is to be able to write C# class libraries, and simply have them available whenever I am writing an app, without needing to explicitly add a reference to each library in each new app I write. Whenever I want to edit a library, I could simply open that Visual Studio project, edit it, and then build it again. Then the updated library is available to all of the apps I have consuming that library.

Comment: What would be your expectation of what happens when another developer needs to update the project?

Comment: FWIW, I think what you're after is a custom project template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2017

Comment: @TiesonT. I honestly have not thought about other developers with this; I was only thinking for personal use. I suspect an entirely different approach would be needed if I wanted to write a library to release to other developers. Perhaps NuGet would be useful? Are there conventions or best practices for writing libraries? I have been unsuccessful in my search so far. I'll take a look at the link.

Comment: I've used NuGet packages for "internal" assemblies I wanted to share across projects. If it's something that needs to be private, you can use something like MyGet, or create a package and share it on a network share somewhere (as a few examples). If you have a CI server like TeamCity, it can actually be configured to work as a NuGet source, as well. One nice thing about going the package route is that the projects using the assembly can choose when to update the package, assuming you push a new version at some point.

Comment: As for best practices, that's a broad subject. At a minimum you'd want to make sure you version your assemblies "correctly": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/best-practices-for-assembly-loading. Then, of course, kids these days expect you use [semver](https://semver.org/) and get upset if you don't, so...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why would you want to do this, cause it's a simple thing to set the using statements in the top of the page. But i'm almost certain that you can't get arround this.

This post states that: [answer to get around of using statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7588728/3489204)

Comment: The goal is not to get around that step, but rather the step before it. Before I can even use a `using` statement, I must add a reference to the library in the Visual Studio project. I don't need to do that preliminary step for something like `System.Collections`... I simply add the `using System.Collections` statement and it just works. The goal is to get my own libraries to be usable like that, without the preliminary step. I updated the question to hopefully clarify.

Comment: Now i see what you mean...
I think that ReSharp plugin does that in some cases.
I think that it does add the reference of the solution projects and others system.* libraries. If you're missing them and you click the Ctrl+. shortcut.