# asp.net vb.net app_code alternative

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, app-code

I'm trying to find an alternative to the app_code folder to import my classes in my aspx files...

Should be fairly easy with Microsoft Visual Studio... but I don't have it, can not have it, will not have it even if I beg my boss...

We have 2 Servers 1 for the development and the other for the public, I don't really know why since I'm new at the place, but on the development server, each developer has a folder to its name.

Now, if I try to place my classes in app_code and I have a error, well I block all of the others programmers until it is fixed.

I'm taking any suggestions to how to proceed to import classes into an .aspx file that it is not a class, but mainly html with some aspx vb.net in <% %>...

Anyway, not the best working environment, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reference a class in all your aspx files specify the namespace in web.config.

```
<add namespace="YourNamespace"/>
```

Look at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438199/c-sharp-namespaces-in-web-config).

**EDIT:**
To import a namespace in a singla aspx page do this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="YourNamespace" %>
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369658/how-to-add-namespace-in-aspx-file)

Comment: Not necessarily in all class, but trying to import any namepsace I define are considered empty, even if their is multiple public class defined in it...

Comment: Please look at my edit above mentioning how to add a namespace in a single aspx file.

Comment: Thank you for your help really, but like I said before, when I try to add namespaces they are not found... So unless their is random rules to namespace naming that I don't know, this solution doesn't seem viable for me...